# How to get feature importance in xgboost?

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm using xgboost to build a model, and try to find the importance of each feature using `get_fscore()`, but it returns `{}`

and my train code is:

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=Y)
watchlist = [(dtrain, 'train')]
param = {'max_depth': 6, 'learning_rate': 0.03}
num_round = 200
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist)
```

So is there any mistake in my train? How to get feature importance in xgboost?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212649/feature-importance-with-xgbclassifier

Comment: Check this [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212649/feature-importance-with-xgbclassifier/49982926#49982926) for getting a xgboost feature importance data frame.

Comment: You need to name the features first. For example, `bst.feature_names=['foo', 'bar', ...]`.

Answer (score 66):

In your code you can get feature importance for each feature in dict form:

```
bst.get_score(importance_type='gain')

>>{'ftr_col1': 77.21064539577829,
   'ftr_col2': 10.28690566363971,
   'ftr_col3': 24.225014841466294,
   'ftr_col4': 11.234086283060112}
```

Explanation: The train() API's method get_score() is defined as:

get_score(fmap='', importance_type='weight')

- **fmap** (str (optional)) – The name of feature map file.
- **importance_type**

  - ‘weight’ - the number of times a feature is used to split the data across all trees.
  - ‘gain’ - the average gain across all splits the feature is used in.
  - ‘cover’ - the average coverage across all splits the feature is used in.
  - ‘total_gain’ - the total gain across all splits the feature is used in.
  - ‘total_cover’ - the total coverage across all splits the feature is used in.

https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html

Comment: Why do I get the following error : AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'get_score' @MLKing

Comment: @arash You need to use `bst.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='gain')` instead

Answer (score 54):

Get the table containing **scores** and **feature names**, and then plot it.

```
feature_important = model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')
keys = list(feature_important.keys())
values = list(feature_important.values())

data = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=keys, columns=["score"]).sort_values(by = "score", ascending=False)
data.nlargest(40, columns="score").plot(kind='barh', figsize = (20,10)) ## plot top 40 features
```

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 33):

Using sklearn API and XGBoost >= 0.81:

```
clf.get_booster().get_score(importance_type="gain")
```

or

```
regr.get_booster().get_score(importance_type="gain")
```

For this to work correctly, when you call `regr.fit` (or `clf.fit`), `X` must be a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: For some reason xgboost seems to have broken the model.feature_importances_ so that is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: My experience is that "X passed to `.fit` must be a pandas.DataFrame" is still true as of 0.9 o/w you get an empty dict.

Answer (score 16):

Build the model from XGboost first

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, plot_importance
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(train, label)
```

this would result in an array. So we can sort it with descending

```
sorted_idx = np.argsort(model.feature_importances_)[::-1]
```

Then, it is time to print all sorted importances and the name of columns together as lists (I assume the data loaded with Pandas)

```
for index in sorted_idx:
    print([train.columns[index], model.feature_importances_[index]])
```

---

Furthermore, we can plot the importances with XGboost built-in function

```
plot_importance(model, max_num_features = 15)
pyplot.show()
```

use `max_num_features` in `plot_importance` to limit the number of features if you want.

Comment: plot_importance() should be called as: plot_importance(model, importance_type = 'gain') . Else different results are obtained with the 'sorted_idx' method. Default importance_type for plot_importance is 'weight'. This is for xgboost version 1.5.0.

Answer (score 13):

According to this [post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-xgboost/) there 3 different ways to get feature importance from Xgboost:

- use built-in feature importance,
- use permutation based importance,
- use shap based importance.

### Built-in feature importance

Code example:

```py
xgb = XGBRegressor(n_estimators=100)
xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
sorted_idx = xgb.feature_importances_.argsort()
plt.barh(boston.feature_names[sorted_idx], xgb.feature_importances_[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Xgboost Feature Importance")
```

Please be aware of what type of feature importance you are using. There are several types of importance, see the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html?highlight=get_score#xgboost.Booster.get_score). The `scikit-learn` like API of Xgboost is returning `gain` importance while `get_fscore` returns `weight` type.

### Permutation based importance

```py
perm_importance = permutation_importance(xgb, X_test, y_test)
sorted_idx = perm_importance.importances_mean.argsort()
plt.barh(boston.feature_names[sorted_idx], perm_importance.importances_mean[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Permutation Importance")
```

This is my preferred way to compute the importance. However, it can fail in case highly colinear features, so be careful! It's using `permutation_importance` from `scikit-learn`.

### SHAP based importance

```py
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(xgb)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_test)
shap.summary_plot(shap_values, X_test, plot_type="bar")
```

To use the above code, you need to have `shap` package installed.

I was running the example analysis on Boston data (house price regression from scikit-learn). Below 3 feature importance:

#### Built-in importance

[image: built in xgboost importance]

#### Permutation based importance

[image: permutation importance]

#### SHAP importance

[image: shap imp]

All plots are for the same model! As you see, there is a difference in the results. I prefer permutation-based importance because I have a clear picture of which feature impacts the performance of the model (if there is no high collinearity).

Answer (score 11):

For feature importance Try this:

Classification:

```
pd.DataFrame(bst.get_fscore().items(), columns=['feature','importance']).sort_values('importance', ascending=False)
```

Regression:

```
xgb.plot_importance(bst)
```

Comment: neither of these solutions currently works. for some reason the model loses the feature names and returns an empty dict.

Comment: Is it a model you just trained or are you loading a pickled model?

Answer (score 10):

For anyone who comes across this issue while using `xgb.XGBRegressor()` the workaround I'm using is to keep the data in a `pandas.DataFrame()` or `numpy.array()` and not to convert the data to `dmatrix()`. Also, I had to make sure the `gamma` parameter is not specified for the XGBRegressor.

```
fit = alg.fit(dtrain[ft_cols].values, dtrain['y'].values)
ft_weights = pd.DataFrame(fit.feature_importances_, columns=['weights'], index=ft_cols)
```

After fitting the regressor `fit.feature_importances_` returns an array of weights which I'm *assuming* is in the same order as the feature columns of the pandas dataframe.

My current setup is Ubuntu 16.04, Anaconda distro, python 3.6, xgboost 0.6, and sklearn 18.1.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know how to get values certainly, but there is a good way to plot features importance:

```
model = xgb.train(params, d_train, 1000, watchlist)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,18))
xgb.plot_importance(model, max_num_features=50, height=0.8, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
fscore = clf.best_estimator_.booster().get_fscore()
```

Comment: not sure if this is applicable for regression but this does not work either as the `clf` doesn't have a `best_estimator_` attribute and the `get_fscore()` returns an empty dict.

Comment: It's for the XGBClassifier

Comment: `AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'best_estimator_'`
Something is wrong here.

Comment: `best_estimator_` is required only if you are using something like `GridSearchCV` for parameter tuning. If you are using xgboost without this, you should just do `clf.booster().get_fscore()`

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using XGBRegressor, try with: `model.get_booster().get_score()`.

That returns the results that you can directly visualize through  `plot_importance` command

Comment: I am using XGBClassifier, however this is the only code that returns value for the features, I am wondering why!

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me, this was the code I ended up with, to sort features by importance.

```
from collections import Counter
Counter({k: v for k, v in sorted(model.get_fscore().items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse = True)}).most_common
```

just replace model with the name of your model and everything will be there. Of course I'm doing the same thing twice, there's no need to order a dict before passing to counter, but I figure it wouldn't hurt to leave it there in case anyone hates Counters.