# Feature Importance with XGBClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

Hopefully I'm reading this wrong but in the XGBoost library [documentation](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn), there is note of extracting the feature importance attributes using `feature_importances_` much like sklearn's random forest.

However, for some reason, I keep getting this error: `AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'`

My code snippet is below:

```
from sklearn import datasets
import xgboost as xg
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
Y = iris.target
Y = iris.target[ Y < 2] # arbitrarily removing class 2 so it can be 0 and 1
X = X[range(1,len(Y)+1)] # cutting the dataframe to match the rows in Y
xgb = xg.XGBClassifier()
fit = xgb.fit(X, Y)
fit.feature_importances_
```

It seems that you can compute feature importance using the `Booster` object by calling the `get_fscore` attribute. The only reason I'm using `XGBClassifier` over `Booster` is because it is able to be wrapped in a sklearn pipeline. Any thoughts on feature extractions? Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your snippet.  What version of XGBoost do you have?

Comment: from my `pip freeze` , i have `xgboost==0.4a30`

Comment: Does this help? https://www.kaggle.com/mmueller/liberty-mutual-group-property-inspection-prediction/xgb-feature-importance-python/comments

Comment: I have seen this before. The problem is however, is that the `get_fscore` method is bound to the `Booster` object rather than `XGBClassifier` from my understanding. See the doc [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.Booster)

Comment: I have 0.4 and your snippet works with no problem.

Comment: Hrm this is odd. The current version is `0.4a30` right? It appears so looking at their [repo](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost)

Comment: @MinhMai using `feature_importances_` via booster() are you able to get the column names accurately ? In my case, it throws a KeyError that not certain features are not present in the data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the comments indicate, I suspect your issue is a versioning one. However if you do not want to/can't update, then the following function should work for you.

```
def get_xgb_imp(xgb, feat_names):
    from numpy import array
    imp_vals = xgb.booster().get_fscore()
    imp_dict = {feat_names[i]:float(imp_vals.get('f'+str(i),0.)) for i in range(len(feat_names))}
    total = array(imp_dict.values()).sum()
    return {k:v/total for k,v in imp_dict.items()}


>>> import numpy as np
>>> from xgboost import XGBClassifier
>>> 
>>> feat_names = ['var1','var2','var3','var4','var5']
>>> np.random.seed(1)
>>> X = np.random.rand(100,5)
>>> y = np.random.rand(100).round()
>>> xgb = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=10)
>>> xgb = xgb.fit(X,y)
>>> 
>>> get_xgb_imp(xgb,feat_names)
{'var5': 0.0, 'var4': 0.20408163265306123, 'var1': 0.34693877551020408, 'var3': 0.22448979591836735, 'var2': 0.22448979591836735}
```

Comment: Interesting approach! However, would it matter if I tune my parameters for `XGBClassifer`? How would I ensure that it would match the parameters for `Booster`

Comment: you're referencing the booster() object within your XGBClassifer() object, so it will match: `xgb.booster()`

Comment: I realized something strange, and is that supposed to happen? The values returned from xgb.booster().get_fscore() that should contain values for all columns the model is trained for? Because I find 2 columns missing from imp_vals, which are present in train columns, but not as key in imp_cols

Comment: I had to use `xgb.get_booster().get_fscore()`. Otherwise I was getting `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. I am using xgboost 0.6.

Comment: I pickled my XGB object and am unable to call `get_booster()`: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 193, in get_booster raise XGBoostError('need to call fit or load_model beforehand') `

Comment: As for today, I have the following error: ```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[152], line 1
----> 1 get_xgb_imp(xgb_model,columns_names)

Cell In[151], line 3, in get_xgb_imp(xgb, feat_names)
      1 def get_xgb_imp(xgb, feat_names):
      2     from numpy import array
----> 3     imp_vals = xgb.booster().get_fscore()
      4     imp_dict = {feat_names[i]:float(imp_vals.get('f'+str(i),0.)) for i in range(len(feat_names))}
      5     total = array(imp_dict.values()).sum()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable```

Answer (score 15):

For `xgboost`, if you use `xgb.fit()`,then you can use the following method to get feature importance.

```
import pandas as pd
xgb_model=xgb.fit(x,y)
xgb_fea_imp=pd.DataFrame(list(xgb_model.get_booster().get_fscore().items()),
columns=['feature','importance']).sort_values('importance', ascending=False)
print('',xgb_fea_imp)
xgb_fea_imp.to_csv('xgb_fea_imp.csv')

from xgboost import plot_importance
plot_importance(xgb_model, )
```

Answer (score 8):

I found out the answer. It appears that version `0.4a30` does not have `feature_importance_` attribute. Therefore if you install the xgboost package using `pip install xgboost` you will be unable to conduct feature extraction from the `XGBClassifier` object, you can refer to @David's answer if you want a workaround.

However, what I did is build it from the source by cloning the repo and running `. ./build.sh` which will install version `0.4` where the `feature_importance_` attribute works.

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 5):

Get Feature Importance as a sorted data frame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def get_xgb_imp(xgb, feat_names):
    imp_vals = xgb.booster().get_fscore()
    feats_imp = pd.DataFrame(imp_vals,index=np.arange(2)).T
    feats_imp.iloc[:,0]= feats_imp.index    
    feats_imp.columns=['feature','importance']
    feats_imp.sort_values('importance',inplace=True,ascending=False)
    feats_imp.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    return feats_imp

feature_importance_df = get_xgb_imp(xgb, feat_names)
```

Answer (score 2):

For those having the same problem as [Luís Bianchin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1046584/lu%C3%ADs-bianchin), "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", I found a solution (that works for me at least) [here](http://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/eli5/issues/252).

In short, I found modifying [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2167315/david)'s code from

```
imp_vals = xgb.booster().get_fscore()
```

to

```
imp_vals = xgb.get_fscore()
```

worked for me.

For more detail I would recommend visiting the link above.

Big thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2167315/david) and [ianozsvald](https://github.com/ianozsvald)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in plot_importance function:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier, plot_importance
fit = XGBClassifier().fit(X,Y)
plot_importance(fit)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to built-in feature importance can be:

- permutation-based importance from `scikit-learn` ([`permutation_importance` method](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html#sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance)
- importance with Shapley values ([`shap` package](https://github.com/slundberg/shap))

I really like `shap` package because it provides additional plots. Example:

### Importance Plot

[image: xgboost shap importance]

### Summary Plot

[image: xgboost shap summary]

### Dependence Plot

[image: xgboost shap dependence]

You can read about alternative ways to compute feature importance in Xgboost in this [blog post](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-xgboost/) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

An update of the accepted answer since it no longer works:

```
def get_xgb_imp(xgb_model, feat_names):
    imp_vals = xgb_model.get_fscore()
    imp_dict = {feat: float(imp_vals.get(feat, 0.)) for feat in feat_names}
    total = sum(list(imp_dict.values()))
    return {k: round(v/total, 5) for k,v in imp_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

*It seems like the api keeps on changing. For xgboost version **1.0.2**, just changing from `imp_vals = xgb.booster().get_fscore()` to `imp_vals = xgb.get_booster().get_fscore()` in **@David**'s answer does the trick.* The updated code is -

```
from numpy import array

def get_xgb_imp(xgb, feat_names):
    imp_vals = xgb.get_booster().get_fscore()
    imp_dict = {feat_names[i]:float(imp_vals.get('f'+str(i),0.)) for i in range(len(feat_names))}
    total = array(imp_dict.values()).sum()
    return {k:v/total for k,v in imp_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to get feature_importance. Also, I used DictVectorizer() in the pipeline for one_hot_encoding. If you use

```
v = DictVectorizer()
X_to_dict = X.to_dict("records")
X_transformed = v.fit_transform(X_to_dict)
feature_names = v.get_feature_names()
best_model.get_booster().feature_names = feature_names
xgb.plot_importance(best_model.get_booster())
```

You can obtain the f_score plot. But I wanted to plot the feature importance against the feature names. So I modified it further.
`f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 30)) plt.barh(feature_names, best_model.feature_importances_) plt.xticks(rotation = 90) plt.show()`