# Does xgboost have feature_importances_?

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I'm calling xgboost via its scikit-learn-style Python interface:

```
model = xgboost.XGBRegressor() 
%time model.fit(trainX, trainY)
testY = model.predict(testX)
```

Some sklearn models tell you which importance they assign to features via the attribute `feature_importances`. This doesn't seem to exist for the `XGBRegressor`:

```
model.feature_importances_
AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-fbaa36f9f167> in <module>()
----> 1 model.feature_importances_

AttributeError: 'XGBRegressor' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

The weird thing is: For a collaborator of mine the attribute `feature_importances_` is there! What could be the issue?

These are the versions I have:

```
In [2]: xgboost.__version__
Out[2]: '0.6'

In [4]: sklearn.__version__
Out[4]: '0.18.1'
```

... and the xgboost C++ library from github, commit `ef8d92fc52c674c44b824949388e72175f72e4d1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you install xgboost? Did you build the package after cloning it from github, as described in the doc?

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html

As in this answer:

[Feature Importance with XGBClassifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212649/feature-importance-with-xgbclassifier)

There always seems to be a problem with the pip-installation and xgboost. Building and installing it from your build seems to help.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks - it seems that the package distributed via pip is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
model.get_booster().get_score(importance_type='weight')
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, XGBoost model has feature importance details

Try the following : (It also gives you the names of the features and its weightage)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

bars = xgb_model.get_booster().feature_names
y_pos = np.arange(len(bars))
pyplot.bar(range(len(xgb_model.feature_importances_)), xgb_model.feature_importances_)
pyplot.xticks(y_pos, xgb_model.get_booster().feature_names, color='black', rotation=45, fontsize='25', horizontalalignment='right')
pyplot.show()
```

[Feature importance plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EkX4.png)

Answer (score -1):

This is useful for you,maybe.

`xgb.plot_importance(bst)`

And this is the link:[plot](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_intro.html#plotting)