# XGBoost plot importance has no property max_num_features

Tags: python, feature-selection, xgboost

xgboost's [plotting API](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.plotting) states:

```
xgboost.plot_importance(booster, ax=None, height=0.2, xlim=None, ylim=None, title='Feature importance', xlabel='F score', ylabel='Features', importance_type='weight', max_num_features=None, grid=True, **kwargs)¶
```

Plot importance based on fitted trees.

Parameters:

```
booster (Booster, XGBModel or dict) – Booster or XGBModel instance, or dict taken by Booster.get_fscore()
...
max_num_features (int, default None) – Maximum number of top features displayed on plot. If None, all features will be displayed.
```

In my implementation, however, running:

```
booster_ = XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1, max_depth=3, n_estimators=100, 
                      silent=False, objective='binary:logistic', nthread=-1, 
                      gamma=0, min_child_weight=1, max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, 
                      colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1, reg_alpha=0,
                      reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, base_score=0.5, seed=0)

booster_.fit(X_train, y_train)

from xgboost import plot_importance
plot_importance(booster_, max_num_features=10)
```

Returns:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property max_num_features
```

While running it without the parameter `max_num_features` plots correctly the entire feature set (which in my case is gigantic, ~10k features). 
Any ideas of what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Details:

```
> python -V
  Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda custom (x86_64)

> pip freeze | grep xgboost
  xgboost==0.4a30
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to upgrade your xgboost library to 0.6. It should solve the problem.
To upgrade the package, try this:

```
$ pip install -U xgboost
```

If you get an error, try this:

```
$ brew install gcc@5
$ pip install -U xgboost
```

(Refer to this https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1501)

Comment: Yep! XGboost doesn't have the nicest docs, but after figuring that out it worked. I'll accept your answer as it is more relevant now (kinda forgot about having asked this question).

Answer (score 2):

Until further notice I've solved the problem (at least partially) with this script:

```
def feat_imp(df, model, n_features):

    d = dict(zip(df.columns, model.feature_importances_))
    ss = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
    top_names = ss[0:n_features]

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
    plt.title("Feature importances")
    plt.bar(range(n_features), [d[i] for i in top_names], color="r", align="center")
    plt.xlim(-1, n_features)
    plt.xticks(range(n_features), top_names, rotation='vertical')

 feat_imp(filled_train_full, booster_, 20)
```

[image]

Comment: With XGBRegressor, I get `feature_importances_` not found error.

Comment: @xgdgsc you may need to update xgboost. feature_importances_ is clearly part of their most recent API. See this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38212649/feature-importance-with-xgbclassifier

Answer (score 2):

Despite the title of the documentation [webpage](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.plotting) ("Python API Reference - xgboost 0.6 documentation"), it does not contain the documentation for the 0.6 release of `xgboost`. Instead it *seems* to contain the documentation for the latest git master branch.

The 0.6 release of `xgboost` was made on [Jul 29 2016](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/releases/tag/v0.60):

```
This is a stable release of 0.6 version

@tqchen tqchen released this on Jul 29 2016 · 245 commits to master since this release
```

The commit that  added `plot_importance()`'s `max_num_features`was made on [Jan 16 2017](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/commit/a7d28337669cf51eec40086b7e0ab362df5b0316):

As a further check, let's inspect the 0.60 release tarball:

```
pushd /tmp
curl -SLO https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/archive/v0.60.tar.gz
tar -xf v0.60.tar.gz 
grep num_features xgboost-0.60/python-package/xgboost/plotting.py
# .. silence.
```

Therefore this seems to be a documentation bug with the xgboost project.

Answer (score 0):

Just something to add here. I still have this error and I believe others have too. So until this issue is resolved here is another way to achieve the same thing:

```
max = 50
xgboost.plot_importance(dict(sorted(bst.get_fscore().items(), reverse = True, key=lambda x:x[1])[:max]), ax = ax, height = 0.8)
```

as you can also pass a dict to the plot, you basically get the fscore, sort the items in reverse order, select the desired number of top features then convert back to dict.

I hope this helps anyone else with the same issue trying to plot only a certian number features by their importance starting form the top feature instead of plotting them all.