# XGBoost get feature importance as a list of columns instead of plot

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am wondering if you we can get the feature importance as a list of columns instead of a plot. This is what I have

```
xg_reg = xgb.train(params=params, dtrain=data_dmatrix, num_boost_round=10)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xgb.plot_importance(xg_reg)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [5,5]
plt.show()
```

Which gives me this plot

[image]

I would like to instead just get a list of the top features since I have over 800 different features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xgb.get_score()`. Here are a number of examples: [How to get feature importance in xgboost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627923/how-to-get-feature-importance-in-xgboost)