# Top features of linear regression in python

Tags: python

So I had to create a linear regression in python, but this dataset has over 800 columns. Is there anyway to see what columns are contributing most to the linear regression model? Thank you.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, and better suited for [statistics.se]

Answer (score 0):

Look at the coefficients for each of the features. Ignore the sign of the coefficient:

- A large absolute value means the feature is heavily contributing.
- A value close to zero means the feature is not contributing much.
- A value of zero means the feature is not contributing at all.

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of say the top 20 columns is what I'm really asking I guess.

Comment: Take the coefficients, sort them by absolute value (largest first), then slice the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the correlation between each independent variable and dependent variable, for example:

corr(X1, Y)

corr(X2, Y)

.

.

.

corr(Xn, Y)

and you can test the model selecting the N most correlated variable.

There are more sophisticated methods to perform dimensionality reduction:

- PCA (Principal Component Analysis)
  (https://towardsdatascience.com/a-one-stop-shop-for-principal-component-analysis-5582fb7e0a9c)
- Forward Feature Construction
- Use XGBoost in order to measure feature importance for each variable and then select the N most important variables
  ([How to get feature importance in xgboost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37627923/how-to-get-feature-importance-in-xgboost))

There are many ways to perform this action and each one has pros and cons.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/dimensionality-reduction-algorithms-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for variables with high correlation I would just do something like this

```
import pandas as pd
cols = df.columns

for c in cols:
    # Set this to whatever you would like
    if df['Y'].corr(df[c]) > .7:
        print(c, df['Y'].corr(df[c]))
```

after you have decided what threshold/columns you want you can append c to a list